# Declaration of attributes for Chtml::Beginform in Yii

Tags: php, yii

Here I am trying to add attributes to the Chtml class of the Yii framework in order to decide the padding of the form using the code given below.

```
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm('user/login',array('style' => 'padding:0 2%;')) ; ?>
<?php echo CHtml::endForm() ; ?>
```

But browser shows the following PHP warning:

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the parameter wrong, from the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#beginForm-detail):

> public static string beginForm(mixed $action='', **string
>   $method='post'**, array $htmlOptions=array ( ))

So your code should be:

```
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm('', 'post', array('style' => 'padding:0 2%;')) ; ?>
<?php echo CHtml::endForm() ; ?>
```

The reason why '' works as the actions, its because it uses [normalizeUrl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#normalizeUrl-detail), which reads:

> If the input parameter is an empty string, the currently requested URL will be returned.

Comment: Thank you. I was not sure of what to keep in the string $method. But how does '' works here?